# Setting up local (reverse) proxy for external services

Tags: nginx, proxy

I am trying to set up a local (reverse) proxy to third party WebApi services using NGINX.

My local Server is supposed to accept HTTP requests, fetch the data from the external ressource using HTTPS and provide me the result via HTTP.

My configuration file so far is

```
events
{
  # Nothing to do here
}

http
{
  server
  {
    # Static HTTP Content
    location /                { root /home/www/htdocs; }
    location /images/         { root /home/www; }

    # GET https://<api-server>/connect?key=<api-key>
    location /api/login
    {
      proxy_pass https://<api-server>/connect;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }

    # POST https://<api-server>/hh
    location /api/hh
    {
      proxy_pass https://<api-server>/hh;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }

  }
}
```

but when I try to

```
curl http://localhost/api/connect?key=ABCD
```

I just receive a 404 whereas the Webservice sends a json response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have location blocks for `/api/login` and `/api/hh`. `/api/connect` is not listed in your config, hence the 404.